# When A and B are of different order given the $\det(AB)$,then calculate $\det(BA)$

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

Let 'A' be a $2 \times 3$ matrix where as B be a $3 \times 2$ matrix if $\det(AB) = 4$ the find value of the $\det(BA)$

My attempt: I took A = 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0  &0\\
        0 & 0  &2\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

 B=
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

It satisfies given condition and I get $\det(BA)=0$ 

 But I have not proved it 

How do I prove that it is always zero

(background)I am 12th grader and I know about adjoint,inverse,determinant,rank of a matrix and the other basics. 
However I do NOT know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of rank of a matrix?

Comment: yes I know basics of rank

Comment: What is the rank of $BA$?
Regarding your example, what can we say about $BA$ if we know that $\det\left(BA\right)=0$?

Comment: In my example  rank is less than 3 but is it always less than 3?

Comment: Yes, when you multiply a 3 by 2 matrix with a 2 by 3 matrix, you arrive at a 3 by 3 matrix whose rank cannot be 3 hence it's singular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will always get $\det(BA)=0$. The reason for this is very simple : $BA$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix with rank at most $2$; thus it is not invertible and thus it has $0$ determinant.

One possible definition of the rank is that it is the dimension of the subspace generated by the columns or the lines of the matrices. The lines of $BA$ are obtained by taking linear combinations of the lines of $A$ : for example, if
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22} \\ b_{31}& b_{32} \end{pmatrix},\ A= \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \end{pmatrix},$$
then the first line of $BA$ is
$$b_{11}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  \end{pmatrix} + b_{12}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \end{pmatrix}.$$

Since the lines of $BA$ are generated by only two lines (of $A$), the dimension of the generated subspace cannot be more than $2$.

This also means that the lines of $BA$ cannot be linearly independent; thus there must be some linear relation between them, which means that when you convert it to echelon matrix you will certainly get a line of $0$s.

Comment: Why exactly is it rank 2 I know only basics of rank could you explain it to me?

Comment: What definition of the rank are you used to?

Comment: The definition I use is that I convert it into echelon matrix and calculate non zero rows

Comment: Ah yes, it is not really obvious then. I'll edit my answer to take that into account.

Comment: Please tell what defination you use and tell me how you got the answer quickly

Comment: quickly? hmmmmn timezones, it's getting late over there, right? :)

Comment: @GopalkrishnaNayak I've tried to make it clearer, let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: @ Arnaud D. I get your answer more clearly now

Answer (score 7):

I think what you are looking for is an answer like this

$B=\begin{pmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22} \\ b_{31}& b_{32} \end{pmatrix}$, $A= \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \end{pmatrix}$,

Then
\begin{align}BA & =\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}a_{11}+b_{12}a_{21} & b_{11}a_{12}+b_{12}a_{22} &  b_{11}a_{13}+b_{12}a_{23}\\ b_{21}a_{11}+b_{22}a_{21} & b_{21}a_{12}+b_{22}a_{22} &b_{21}a_{13}+b_{22}a_{23} \\b_{31}a_{11}+b_{32}a_{21} & b_{31}a_{12}+b_{32}a_{22} &  b_{31}a_{13}+b_{32}a_{23}  \end{pmatrix} \\ & =\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}a_{11}+b_{12}a_{21}+0.0 & b_{11}a_{12}+b_{12}a_{22}+0.0 &  b_{11}a_{13}+b_{12}a_{23}+0.0\\ b_{21}a_{11}+b_{22}a_{21}+0.0 & b_{21}a_{12}+b_{22}a_{22}+0.0 &b_{21}a_{13}+b_{22}a_{23}+0.0 \\b_{31}a_{11}+b_{32}a_{21}+0.0 &b_{31}a_{12}+b_{32}a_{22}+0.0 &  b_{31}a_{13}+b_{32}a_{23} +0.0 \end{pmatrix}\\ & =\begin{pmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12} & 0\\ b_{21} & b_{22} &0 \\b_{31} & b_{32} &  0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} &a_{23} \\0 & 0 &  0 \end{pmatrix}.\end{align}

Let $C=\begin{pmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12} & 0\\ b_{21} & b_{22} &0 \\b_{31} & b_{32} &  0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $D= \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} &a_{23} \\0 & 0 &  0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Now, $BA=CD$. Therefore, $\det(BA)=\det(CD)=\det(C)\cdot \det(D)=0\cdot 0=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ T = BA $, then $ T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ is a linear transformation with nontrivial kernel, as $ A : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ cannot be an injection. Thus, it is not invertible, and $ \det(T) = 0 $.