# $A=\pmatrix{1&2&3&4&5\\2&3&4&5&6}.$ Find $\det(A^TA)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Suppose $$A=\pmatrix{1&2&3&4&5\\2&3&4&5&6}$$ Find $\det(A^TA)$.

I know exactly how to calculate it by writing it as a $5\times5$ matrix. But how to calculate it smartly?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782600/when-a-and-b-are-of-different-order-given-the-detab-then-calculate-detba

Answer (score 38, accepted):

- Rank of $A$ is $2$, hence $A^TA$ cannot be rank $5$ and it must be singular.
- Hence the determinant must be $0$.

Comment: Can you explain why the first bullet point is true?

Comment: We know that $rank(AB) \le \min(rank(A), rank(B))$.